# JsonSlurper inconsistently parses Strings? Sometimes returns String, sometimes returns ArrayList?

Tags: groovy, jsonslurper

```
"context A": {
    "name": "parent A",
    "operation": {
        "name": "op A",
        "convenienceType": {
            "descriptor": "View",
            "id": "view_id"
        }
    },
    "context B": {
        "name": "child B",
        "operation": {
            "name": "op B",
            "convenienceType": {
                "descriptor": "View",
                "id": "view_id"
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

I've got an `operation` object that's repeated in my JSON but for different contexts. The `convenienceType` field of the operation is basically from an enum-selection, so the convenienceType with the `"View"` descriptor is the same object no matter the context the `operation` object was generated from.

I'm using JSONSlurper in my Groovy script to parse this. Here's what I'm seeing:

At context A level:

`operation.convenienceType.descriptor // evaluates to "View" (string)`

At context B level:

`operation.convenienceType.descriptor // evaluates to ["View"] (array)`

So when I try to do something like

`operation.convenienceType.descriptor.toLowerCase`

It works for context A but at context B I get an error since my code is complaining there is no `toLowerCase` method for arrays.

Anyone know why this might happen...?

Comment: Please add the code and also the exact JSON that shows that problem.  The one you provided seems oddly nested and if you try it out, you will see, that it works and there is no random behaviour.  Most likely you _have_ arrays in your json and the code you are using will fall back to implicit spread operator calls.

Comment: I have to believe one of the values in your key-chain is a List (using []), rather than an object (using {}).   Even if it only has one object in the list, it will convert your type in the evaluation to a list.

Answer (score 0):

The example you give doesn't fail in the way you specify:

```
def j = '''{
"context A": {
    "name": "parent A",
    "operation": {
        "name": "op A",
        "convenienceType": {
            "descriptor": "View",
            "id": "view_id"
        }
    },
    "context B": {
        "name": "child B",
        "operation": {
            "name": "op B",
            "convenienceType": {
                "descriptor": "View",
                "id": "view_id"
            }
        }
    }   
}
}'''

import groovy.json.*

def p = new JsonSlurper().parseText(j)

assert p.'context A'.operation.convenienceType.descriptor == 'View'
assert p.'context A'.'context B'.operation.convenienceType.descriptor == 'View'
```